# Check if a string is contained within a specific Map() key

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-map

I have a map which i am populating from a json file, similar to the below

```
key: ConfigItem
value: Var1,Var2,Var3


key: ConfigItem2
value: Var1,Var2,Var3,var4


key: ConfigItem3
value: true
```

i want to be able to run an if statement to check if a value is contained within the "ConfigItem" key, and if so, do something.

I looked at map.get and map.has but i can't seem to be able to figure out how to search a specific key and return if it contains a specific value.

Comment: There is no way to customize the equality algorithm that a map uses if that's what you want. There is a `keys` property that you can iterate however. If your configuration is stored as JSON you shouldn't be using a Map at all...

Comment: @AluanHaddad Yes the config is stored as json, however i wanted a map so that i could update values at runtime without having to reload the app.js

Comment: A Map doesn't provide anything like that. If you need to refresh config from a file you can do so using the file system in a nodejs app or by making an http request in a browser app

Comment: We might be able to help you better if you were to show us actual code rather than pseudo-code. If the value at your specific key is an array, use something like what's in [How do I check if an array includes an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/237104/215552).

Comment: What exactly are you storing as the value, arrays? Comma-separated strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be looking for

```
const map = new Map([
    ["ConfigItem", ["Var1","Var2","Var3"]],
    ["ConfigItem2", ["Var1","Var2","Var3","var4"]],
    ["ConfigItem3", true],
]);

if (map.get("ConfigItem").includes("Var2")) {
    …
}
```

Notice this just uses [Map `get`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get) to access the array value for the `ConfigItem` key, but then uses the normal [Array `includes` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to check if the specific string is contained in it.

Comment: @MohammedEssehemy It seems that the OP already knows that his map has an entry for `ConfigItem`.

Comment: I thought it would be more safe if he isn't sure that the key exists. but if the case as you describe then that's totally fine.